# Book about a boy and girl who are great baseball players

Tags: identification-request

I have pretty limited information about this book, but here goes:

- I read it approximately 6-7 years ago.
- The language of publication was English.
- I found it while browsing in a book store where it was on display, so it probably was a relatively recent book at the time.
- I only read the first bit of the book, since as mentioned I was just wandering around a book store. I therefore can only supply the few details that follow.
- The apparent main character was a boy (probably mid teens) who was an excellent baseball player.
- He was going through some kind of difficulty, which made him decide to stop playing baseball.
- The apparent next-to-main character was a girl about the same age, also an excellent baseball player.
- I believe she was trying to convince him not to give up on baseball.
- I think he took some kind of coaching position on her team.
- As part of that (or perhaps this was what caused him to join the team) he took a turn at bat with the girl pitching. Being not at his best, he missed the first two pitches, but then he found his groove and was able to hit the third pitch.
- I think the boy and the girl went on a walk together and discussed his situation.
- All this was in the beginning of the book, as I only read a little bit of it. I have no idea what happened after that.